# Как правильно извлечь массив?

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Имеется следующий массив:

```
[products] => Array
  (
    [83510] => Array
     (
       [item_id] => 83510
       [product] => Samsung S9
     )
  )
```

Хочу извлечь из него имя товара, но незнаю как это правильно сделать, делаю следующее $korzina['products'] извлекается выше указанный массив. Также покажите пожалуйста как это всё заврнуть в foreach, так как могут быть несколько товаров (названий товаров). Спасибо!

**PS. всё дело в том что значение [83510] является идентификатором товара, но я его не могу узнать и следовательно не могу дойти до [product]**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$products = [
    83510 => [
        'item_id' => 83510,
        'product' => 'Samsung S9'
    ]
];

// Извлечь имя товара
$productName = $products[83510]['product'];
echo $productName."\n";

// Пройтись по массиву products и вывести имена
foreach ($products as $productId => $product){
    echo $product['product']."\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: всё дело в том что значение [83510] является идентификатором товара, но я его не могу узнать и следовательно не могу дойти до [product]

Comment: а что за $productId ? здесь должен быть идентификатор товара? если да то пока всё очень трудно с ним

Comment: сработало благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Для обращения к значению массива по ключу следует заключить последний в квадратные скобки

```
$data['key']
```

По этому же принципу можно "добраться" до значений в многомерном массиве

```
$data['key']['key']['key']
```

или в вашем случае

```
$data['products']['83510']['product'];
```

При этом очевидно, что названия ключей можно брать из переменных, например

```
$someKey = '83510';
$cost = $data['products'][$someKey]['product'];
```

Что касается foreach

```
foreach ($data as $key => $product) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: всё дело в том что значение [83510] является идентификатором товара, но я его не могу узнать и следовательно не могу дойти до [product]

Comment: так проходите с помощью foreach , в чём проблема?

Comment: Получается незная идентификатор, можно изнутри неё извлечь другой массив (значение)?

Comment: сработало благодарю!